# Why doesn't this bounded function limit exist?

Tags: limits

Why does $$\lim _{x \to \infty} x\cos x$$ not exist?

Given that $\cos x$ is bounded shouldn't the limit be infinity? Sorry if my post is silly.

Comment: The cosine oscillates between $+1$ and $-1$ and the $x$ that multiplies the cosine amplifies this oscillation.

Comment: Or should it be $-\infty$? Or zero, since $\cos x=0$ infinitely often?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+cos(x)+from+x%3D0..50

Comment: Think about what would happen if $\cos(x) = 0$.

Comment: What on earth do you mean?  The function $x\cos(x)$ is not bounded.

Comment: I said in the description that cos x is bounded.

Comment: Cosx has two different limit points. It is divergent. x is also divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first it may seem like
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\cos x$$
is equal to infinity, because when you look at the graph of the function, you see this:

[image]

It looks like it's going up to infinity, but look at the bottom half of the graph:

[image]

It's also going *down* to $-\infty$. It also crosses the $x$-axis an infinite number to times. The reason it has no limit is because it fluctuates so must. It's true that the maxima of the function approach $\infty$, but the minima approach $-\infty$. It "switches" between large positive, zero, and large negative too often for there to be a limit. No matter how "far out" towards $\infty$ $x$ goes, if you just go a little bit farther, the y-value becomes almost the exact opposite.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes,thank you for the graph it helps me understand it better

Comment: You are quite welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two sequences: $\{x_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}=\{2k\pi\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $\{y_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}=\{2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and note that

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}x_k\cos(x_k)=\infty,$$
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}y_k\cos(y_k)=0.$$